# Models e contextos não aparecem na box de Scaffold

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, scaffold

instalei VS community 2019, e mexendo em um projeto antigo, notei que as classes não ficam mais verdes como tendo referencia, e não consigo acessa-las clicando com o direito e indo em implementação, ou definição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disto, observei que ao tentar criar um novo item via scaffold, as models e contextos não carregam para caixa de dialogo para serem selecionados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja tentei rebuild, recriação do assembly.cs, do diretório .vs, mas sem sucesso

Alguém já passou por isto?

Comment: Nunca tive esse problema com o VS2019 desde de os primeiros testes. Já tentou fazer uma atualização/reinstalação?

Comment: Sem updates... na reinstalação, persistiu.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei exatamente o que aconteceu. Precisei desinstalar a versão 2019, e voltar para a versão 2017 do Visual Studio Community.